# How does a prefetch MSHR works?

Tags: caching, microprocessors, prefetch

I have been reading about Miss Status Handling Registers (MSHR) and using Sim-Alpha for some experiments with cache and I noticed that in the parameters the number of MSHRs can be configured, but also the number of **prefetch MSHRs** .

I have looked in the article which describes the alpha 21264 microprocessor but does not mention it. Neither have I found any online resource where I can look its definition.

Does any one knows how the prefetch MSHR works?

Thanks and best regards.